# Including a CSS property inside another, and the significance if '&' in css

Tags: html, css, sass

I was trying to make an interactive hamburger icon and found a tutorial and the code for it on code pen. The problem is the code I found on code pen does not work on my machine, but it is generating results on code pen. Also, in the CSS, I could see some properties placed within other properties which I did not understand. Please see the code below.

HTML:

```
<div class="nav-icon cross">
<div class="span"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.nav-icon{
  height:70px;
  width:88px;
  position:relative;

  .span {
    height:6px;
    width:55px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:auto;
    background:black;
    transition:all 0.3s;

    &::before,&::after {
      height:6px;
      width:100%;
      background:black;
      position:absolute;
      content:"";
      transition:all 0.3s;
    }
    &::after {
      top:20px;
    }
    &::before {
      top:-20px;
    }
  }

  &.active .span::after {
    top:0;
    transform:rotate(45deg);
  }
    &.active .span::before {
    top:0;
    transform:rotate(-45deg);
  }

  &.active .span{
    background:none;
  }
}
```

Comment: That is not CSS, it's SASS/SCSS and needs a compiler to make those rules translate to CSS

Comment: this is the way we write scss. Here is the link for the same http://sass-lang.com/

Comment: this is not CSS . `.span { &::before { ` is translated in CSS like `.span::before{` .

Comment: Open the CodePen. Click the down-arrow at the top right of the CSS area. Choose "View Compiled CSS"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which you posted it's a SCSS and you have to compile it into CSS

You can read about the scss just following link

**[sass link](http://sass-lang.com/)**

```css
.nav-icon {
  height: 70px;
  width: 88px;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-icon .span {
  height: 6px;
  width: 55px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: black;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.nav-icon .span::before,
.nav-icon .span::after {
  height: 6px;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.nav-icon .span::after {
  top: 20px;
}

.nav-icon .span::before {
  top: -20px;
}

.nav-icon.active .span::after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.nav-icon.active .span::before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.nav-icon.active .span {
  background: none;
}


/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<div class="nav-icon cross">
  <div class="span"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sir first solve a issue then explain it i think that is the best way.

Answer (score 1):

The ampersand (&) symbol in SASS represents a placeholder for the wrapper of the element you're selecting.

For example, if you have:

```
.paragraph {
    color: blue;

    &.active {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

is the same as writing

```
.paragraph {
    color: blue;
}

.paragraph.active {
    color: red;
}
```